# very high memory usage on Jboss 5.1.0.GA server

Tags: memory-management, jvm, jboss5.x

My production server has 32GB RAM running on RHEL 5.6. When JBOSS(5.1.0.GA) starts, memory usage shows 24 GB RAM. Why is JBOSS taking up so much of memory? top command shows 
%CPU - 80% - JAVA.